# Is it possible for the administrator to see the top searches on a Stack Overflow Enterprise site?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-enterprise

Is it possible for a Stack Overflow Enterprise administrator user to see the top searches on the site?

I don't seem to see anything in the administrator settings page for this.

Comment: "*I don't seem to see anything in the administrator settings page for this.*" What administrator settings page are you referring to?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [tag:support] questions about Stack Overflow Enterprise are outside of the scope of Meta Stack Overflow per precedent at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416722/3750257.